# Arduino Client/Server

Tags: ethernet, arduino-uno, iot

I want to send data from an arduino to a web page for remote monitoring as well as send data from the web page to arduino for remote control. Is it possible to create both a client and a server in the same Arduino? Also is there any method by which it is possible to control and monitor an Arduino at the same time?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to have both a client and a server in the Arduino running at the same time. Your second question is not very clear.

Comment: For the second qn, I want to use arduino as a web client, but I should be able to monitor and control the arduino using GET/POST requests. For eg. analog values from a sensor connected to Arduino should be visible on a web page hosted by the web server, at the same time can I use it to obtain data from the webserver for eg. to control an LED connected to the arduino using a switch on that web page? Is there an example available? @Alphonsos_Pangas

Comment: I would place a link in the page generated by the arduino with the folowing format: <a href="/turnon">press here to turn switch on</a> . Then, upon receiving a request, the server should examine the page requested, and if it is the page "/turnon" it would turn on the switch. It is too late right now for me to post code, I 'll do it tomorrow if I remember to.